# Software for symbolic matrix operations

Tags: matrices, symbolic-computation

Is there a software for symbolic manipulation that can treat matrices as whole variables?

For instance:

```
solve A = B + C * A for A
```

where `A`, `B`, `C` are matrices or vectors of generic size and possibly with given assumptions (like Hermitian, positive definite, singular, etc), but without knowing the exact dimensions and elements.

This should yield:

```
A = inv(I - C) * B
```

As far as I understand, applications like Sage, Matlab, Mathematica, SymPy, all treat matrices like sets of individual elements, but they do not truly implement matrix algebra. Am I wrong?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/expressions.html)?

Comment: The [Symbolics.jl](https://symbolics.juliasymbolics.org/dev/manual/arrays/) package for the Julia language looks promising.

Comment: What you say the solver "should yield" requires $C$ to be a square matrix.  So some inference about sizes is needed to reach your conclusion.  I guess different users might be willing to specify more information than others about the dimensions of the matrices.  Also, a solution might exist even if $I-C$ is not invertible, so the problem of giving "generic" symbolic manipulation is more difficult than you perhaps considered.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2820966/339790) look interesting to you?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I tried the following on Sympy/Jupyter/Anaconda:

`from sympy import *`
`n = symbols('n', integer=True)`
`A = MatrixSymbol('A', n, n)`
`Q.invertible(A)`
`b = MatrixSymbol('b', n, 1)`
`x = MatrixSymbol('x', n, 1)`
`solve(A * x - b, x)`

but it gets stuck and never returns the answer `A**(-1) * b`. Anything wrong in my code?

Comment: @MaxThePax What is `Q.invertible(A)`?

Comment: My attempt to tell Sympy that A is invertible. Probably incorrect XD

Comment: @MaxThePax Can you find the documentation for `invertible`?  Even if the matrix is invertible, one would solve the linear system via Gaussian elimination, not via matrix inversion. SymPy is not exactly wrong

Comment: No, I am not looking for Gaussian elimination. I am looking for a software that can solve symbolic matrix equations. The correct answer to `solve A*x=b for x` in this sense is `x=A^(-1)*b`, regardless of the dimensions and elements of `A` as long as it is square and invertible. Gaussian elimination would mean looking at the individual elements. I am looking for a software that follows the left and right multiplication rules, inversion rules, decomposition properties, etc... to solve any matrix equation for a given symbol.

Comment: Documentation for `Q`: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/assumptions/assume.html

Comment: @MaxThePax Well, perhaps SymPy is not smart enough for that...

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I see, thank you very much for your input anyways!

Comment: @MaxThePax The bright side is that, since SymPy is (or was) open-source, you can improve it if you have the skills, time and inclination.

Answer (score 0):

Sympy i think it is very promising.
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/expressions.html
Edit: I didnt notice rodrigos comment.

Comment: I tried the following on Sympy/Jupyter/Anaconda:

`from sympy import *`
`n = symbols('n', integer=True)`
`A = MatrixSymbol('A', n, n)`
`Q.invertible(A)`
`b = MatrixSymbol('b', n, 1)`
`x = MatrixSymbol('x', n, 1)`
`solve(A * x - b, x)`

but it gets stuck and never returns the answer `A**(-1) * b`. Anything wrong in my code?